# Http error 502 when hitting API from PyCharm

Tags: apache, tomcat, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, documentum

I am using Apache Tomcat 9 to run documentum rest APIs from Windows server but whenever I am hitting the API from PyCharm it is giving the 502 error (http response code) and the text is:

> **The server you are requesting is not responding. This is not a proxy issue. To solve the problem contact server administrator. Your sending address on the internet is Ip address.

The same APIs are running fine from POSTMAN.

API: `http://localhost:8080/dctm-rest/repositories`

Please help and suggest how to resolve this http error of 502 when hitting API from PyCharm.

Comment: are you running your Postman from same machine as pycharm code? Is proxy included anyhow?

Comment: @miki yeah running same postman and pycharm from same mavchine and I included the proxy as well in code but thing is when i am giving https://localhost ,it is not working but when iam giving http://<ip address> it is working fine without any error.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/